# Appboy iOS implementation

Tags: ios, xcode, push-notification, appboy, braze

I have implmented appboy in iOS app for push notifications.
This was working fine previously but from last two days its giving an error when I am trying to test a push.

**"None of the users with email or id asd111@gmail.com have matching push tokens for iOS Push"**
[image]

And previously everything was good and working fine.
same p12 certificates same pem. Any suggestion would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing same issue a while ago and ended up uploading another p12 certificate. It worked like a charm ;). Also make sure you are testing in the same environment for which appboy is configured for! I mean, if you are using development certificates to test push notifications than you must upload development SSL certificate (p12) and if you are using distribution certificate than you must upload production SSL certificate. Hope it helps!